# Run specific job in Gitlab CI base on a condition

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a repo `QA/tests` which I want to run all the jobs when there is a push to this repo.

I used a script to generate the jobs dynamically:

```yaml
job-generator:
  stage: generate
  tags:
    - kuber
  script:
    - scripts/generate-job.sh > generated-job.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-job.yml

main:
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-job.yml
        job: job-generator
    strategy: depend
```

At the next step, I have another repo `products/first` which I want to run a specific job in `QA/tests` at every push in the `products/first` so I tried:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

tests:
  stage: test
  variables:
    TARGET: first
  trigger:
    project: QA/tests
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

Then I tried to define a global `TARGET: all` variable in my main `gitlab-ci.yml` and override it with the `TARGET: first` in the above YAML.

**generate-job.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PRODUCTS=("first" "second" "third")

for P in "${PRODUCTS[@]}"; do
cat << EOF
$P:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - kuber
  script:
    - echo -e "Hello from $P"
  rules:
    - if: '"$TARGET" == "all"'
      when: always
    - if: '"$TARGET" == $P'
      when: always

EOF
done
```

But no results. the downstream pipeline doesn't have any job at all!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with:

**gitlab-ci.yml:**

```yaml
variables:
  TARGET: all

job-generator:
  stage: generate
  tags:
    - kuber
  script:
    - scripts/generate-job.sh > generated-job.yml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - generated-job.yml

main:
  variables:
    CHILD_TARGET: $TARGET
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: generated-job.yml
        job: job-generator
    strategy: depend
```

and use `CHILD_TARGET` in my **generate-job.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PRODUCTS=("first" "second" "third")

for P in "${PRODUCTS[@]}"; do
cat << EOF
$P:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - kuber
  script:
    - echo -e "Hello from $P"
  rules:
    - if: '\$CHILD_TARGET == "all"'
      when: always
    - if: '\$CHILD_TARGET == "$P"'
      when: always

EOF
done
```

So I could call it from other projects like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

e2e-tests:
  stage: test
  variables:
    TARGET: first
  trigger:
    project: QA/tests
    branch: master
    strategy: depend
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is now helpful, but this looks like an over complicated approach from the outside. I have to say i have limited knowledge and my answer is based on assumption:

1. the `QA/tests` repository contains certain test cases for all repositories
2. `QA/tests` has the sole purpose of containing the tests, not an overview over the projects etc.

**My Suggestion**

As `QA/tests` is only containing tests which should be executed against each project, i would create a docker image out of it which is contains all the tests and can actually execute them. (lets calls it `qa-tests:latest`)

Within my projects i would add a step which uses this images, with my source code of the project and executes the tests:

```yaml
qa-test:
  image: qa-tests:latest
  script:
    - echo "command to execute scripts"
  # add rules here accordingly
```

this would solve the issue with each push into the repositories. For an easier usage, i could create a `QA-Tests.gitlab-ci.yml` file which can be included by the sub-projects with

```yaml
include:
  - project: QA/tests
    file: QA-Tests.gitlab-ci.yml
```

this way you do not need to do updates with in the repositories if the ci snippet changes.

Finally to trigger the execution on each push, you only need to trigger the pipelines of the subprojects from the `QA/tests`.

**Disclaimer**

As i said, i have only a limited few, as the goal is described but not the motivation. With this approach you remove some of the directive calls - mainly the ones triggering from sub projects to QA/tests. And it generates a clear structure, but it might not fit your needs.